Autodesk Forge error #9 - No viewable content
I am trying to upload my model using Autodesk Forge. I got all the necessary tokens and URN using Postman. I wrote the code using the instructions, but it gives error #9. I still haven't figured out how to fix it.
I found such a message on the page, I didn't really understand how it works, but if I understood correctly, then this is a message that my requests are being blocked, maybe because of this I get such an error, but I couldn't fix it either
I've tried downloading other models, but to no avail
I hid my token, but left the string with the URN, because it seems to me that I might somehow incorrectly specify it
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Autodesk Forge Viewer</title>
    <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.54/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #forgeViewer {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="forgeViewer"></div>

    <script>
        var options = {
            env: 'AutodeskProduction',
            api: 'derivativeV2',
            getAccessToken: function(onTokenReady) {
                var accessToken = '<my_token>';
                var expireTimeSeconds = 60 * 30;
                onTokenReady(accessToken, expireTimeSeconds);
            }
        };
        var documentId = 'urn:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bG9yZDYwNi9yYWNhZHZhbmNlZHNhbXBsZXByb2plY3QucnZ0';

        Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function() {
            var viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('forgeViewer'));
            viewer.start();
            Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, function(document) {
                var defaultModel = document.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
                viewer.loadDocumentNode(document, defaultModel);
            }, function(errorMsg) {
                console.error('Load Error: ' + errorMsg);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>    ```
I downloaded an example .rvt model from the autodesk examples website. Yes, I noticed that when executing get manifest, it returns false. I just don't understand why, I moved the model to the Postman/files folder. I checked the box so that it can take files from any source, but it is still false
```    {
    "type": "manifest",
    "hasThumbnail": "false",
    "status": "failed",
    "progress": "complete",
    "region": "US",
    "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bG9yZDYwNi9yYWNfYWR2YW5jZWRfc2FtcGxlX3Byb2plY3QucnZ0",
    "version": "1.0",
    "derivatives": [
        {
            "name": "LMV Bubble",
            "hasThumbnail": "false",
            "status": "failed",
            "progress": "complete",
            "messages": [
                {
                    "type": "error",
                    "message": "Tr worker fail to unzip.",
                    "code": "TranslationWorker-InternalFailure"
                }
            ],
            "outputType": "svf"
        }
    ]
}    ```


The above code worked just fine for me to view a model. If you're unable to view the model, please check the manifest(https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/manifest/urn-manifest-GET/) to make sure the translation is a success. I don't see an upload functionality in your code. Many of our samples have upload functionality. like https://oss-manager.autodesk.io/#  https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-simple-viewer-nodejs https://aps-extensions.autodesk.io/ etc.. you can reuse the code from these samples.

I downloaded an example .rvt model from the autodesk examples website. Yes, I noticed that when executing get manifest, it returns false. I just don't understand why, I moved the model to the Postman/files folder. I checked the box so that it can take files from any source, but it is still false
... "type": "manifest",
"hasThumbnail": "false",
"status": "failed",
"progress": "complete",
"region": "US",
...

..."derivatives": [
{
"name": "LMV Bubble",
"hasThumbnail": "false",
"status": "failed",
"progress": "complete",
"messages": [
{
"type": "error",
"message": "Tr worker fail to unzip.",
"code": "TranslationWorker-InternalFailure"
} ...

please give me the link to the file, I will test it and let you know.
